# Unable to save BufferedImage from applet using ImageIO.write

Tags: java, image, applet, nullpointerexception

I'm loading a BufferedImage and drawing a rectangle over it. I then want to save the result as a `png`. But the image will not save using `ImageIO.write`. I don't thinking I'm drawing the image correctly.  My current code is below:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class goal extends Applet implements MouseListener, ActionListener {

    Connection connection = null;
    BufferedImage img = null;
    Label ld;
    URL url;
    int x, y, w, h, entry, x2, y2, w2, h2;
    double temp;
    String id;
    TextField percent;
    Button enter;
    Boolean save = false;
    File outputfile = new File("C:/java temp/saved.png");

    public void init() {
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        addMouseListener(this);
        this.setLayout(null);

        x = 87;
        y = 461;
        w = 22;
        h = 0;
        percent = new TextField();
        percent.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 30);
        this.add(percent);
        percent.setVisible(true);
        percent.addActionListener(this);

        enter = new Button("ENTER");
        enter.setBounds(65, 10, 50, 30);
        enter.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(enter);
        enter.setBackground(Color.blue);
        enter.setVisible(true);

        id = ("sales-goal.png");
        try {
            URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), id);
            img = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // Graphics2D g=img.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(img, 10, 10, this);
        // g.drawImage(img,null,10,10);

        Color myColor = Color.decode("#32004b");
        g.setColor(myColor);
        g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        // g.fillRect(83,451,26,10);
        if (entry >= 60) {
            g.fillRect(x2, y2, w2, h2);

        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Graphics g = getGraphics();

        if (e.getSource() == percent) {
            entry = Integer.parseInt(percent.getText());

            if (entry < 101) {
                y = 461;

                temp = entry;
                temp = temp * 2.65;
                temp = Math.round(temp);
                h = (int) temp;
                y = y - h;
            }
        }

        if (e.getSource() == enter) {
            g.drawString(outputfile + "", 10, 10);
            save = true;
            try {
                ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);
            } catch (IOException i) {
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    {
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "will not save", what actually happens?  Is an exception thrown by this code?  Is the file created but with unexpected content?  Is the file not created at all?

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {}`  Don't ignore exception information,  especially not in broken code!  replace that with `catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace() }` for each catch.

Comment: the file is not created at all, the exception is not thrown

Comment: @user1329836 - No exception is thrown because you are swallowing it. See Andrew's comment above.

Comment: Ive added the exception g.drawString("exception: " + i.getMessage(),50,50);i.printStackTrace();

Comment: ive added the exception and ran the debugger with no results              if (e.getSource()==enter)
        {
            g.drawString(outputfile+"",10,10);
            save=true;
            try{
                    ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);
               } catch (IOException i) {g.drawString("exception: " + i.getMessage(),50,50);i.printStackTrace();}
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote some code to save the contents of a JPanel in an applet once.  Hopefully this will help:

```
private void saveView(File saveTo, JPanel view) {

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(view.getPreferredSize().width,
        view.getPreferredSize().height,
        BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);

    view.print(image.getGraphics());

    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", saveTo);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Handle exception
    }
}
```

It definitely worked, and it doesn't look too dissimilar from your own.

Maybe put an `e.printStackTrace()` in your `catch (IOException e) {}` to see if there's an exception being thrown?

(And as Vespasian said, your file path is suspcicious...)

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look into File.Seperator.
If you want to draw to the image you will have to use

```
Graphics2D g=(Graphics2D)img.getGraphics();
```

Edit: Wrong information on file seperator / under windows was removed

Comment: Have you tested this? I don't think this is true

Comment: In general "C:/java temp/saved.png" is possible under Windows thanks to unnamed spirits at Microsoft. The directory needs to exist however: `outputfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();`.

Comment: `Graphics2D g= img.createGraphics(); // look ma, no cast!` ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I dont thinking im drawing the image correctly..

Time to 'stop thinking' & start debugging.  ;)

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:204)
    at goal.actionPerformed(goal.java:87) ...
```

Using this source altered to show at least one stack trace.  It is left as an exercise for the user to fill in the calls to `printStackTrace()` for each catch.

```
// <applet code=goal width=400 height=200></applet>
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class goal extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    BufferedImage img=null;
    Label ld;
    URL url;
    int x,y,w,h,entry,x2,y2,w2,h2;
    double temp;
    String id;
    TextField percent;
    Button enter;
    Boolean save=false;
    File outputfile = new File("C:/java temp/saved.png");

    public void init()
    {
        Graphics g= getGraphics();
        this.setLayout(null);

        x=87; y=461; w=22; h=0;
        percent=new TextField();
        percent.setBounds(10,10,50,30);
        this.add(percent);
        percent.setVisible(true);
        percent.addActionListener(this);

        enter=new Button ("ENTER");
        enter.setBounds(65,10,50,30);
        enter.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(enter);
        enter.setBackground(Color.blue);
        enter.setVisible(true);

        id=("sales-goal.png");
        try {
            URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(),id);
            img = ImageIO.read(url);
        }   catch (IOException e) {}
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(img,10,10,this);

        Color myColor = Color.decode("#32004b");
        g.setColor(myColor);
        g.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
        if(entry>=60)
        {
            g.fillRect(x2,y2,w2,h2);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        Graphics g= getGraphics();

        if (e.getSource()==percent)
        {
            entry= Integer.parseInt(percent.getText());

            if(entry<101)
            {
                y=461;

                temp=entry;
                temp=temp*2.65;
                temp=Math.round(temp);
                h=(int)temp;
                y=y-h;
            }
        }

        if (e.getSource()==enter)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
            g.drawString(outputfile+"",10,10);
            save=true;
            try {
                ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

#### Further notes:

This code has problems beyond the NPE.

1. Expecting to save a `File` from an applet.
2. Coding using AWT components (`Applet` etc.) When the better toolkit is Swing (`JApplet`).
3. (Coding an applet when a free floating frame is better)
4. Calling `getGraphics()` on the GUI.
5. Using a `null` layout.  (The text of button already looks 'crowded')
6. The blue BG of the button makes it hard to read the text.

..but one thing at a time.